# How to fire onChange event on ZK Textbox?

Tags: textbox, onchange, zk

In ZK, say I have a Textbox

```
<textbox id="tb"/>
```

And then in java I do

```
private Textbox tb;
tb.setValue("some new value");
```

I want that when I set this value, to trigger the onChange (or onOK) method of the textbox, as if the user has inputed the new text himself and pressed enter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the java you just have to do:

```
private Textbox tb;
tb.setValue("some new value");
Events.postEvent("onChange", tb, null);
```

Check [this](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/Event_Handling/Event_Firing) to more information.